# Override speed limit per PC of a public wifi in Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, wireless-networking, wireless-router, internet-speed

I have a public wifi in my hostel but it never provide download speed more 1mbps. I am sure it has a speed limit of 1mbps per P.C because it always give download speed of 1mbps. If I connect two or more PC to same wifi each of them get speed of 1mbps. Is there any way to prevent wifi from restricting speed to 1mbps in Windows 7.

Note: There are several wifi router in my hostel each with speed limit of 1mbps. So, as an alternate if it is possible to connect to many wifi at same time to increase speed.

Comment: That's an unethical question. You need access to the router's admin interface. The only ways to do that are by hacking (something we won't help you doing), or asking management for the password. If you are going to ask management, then just go and ask for a speed increase, instead of trying to do this sneakingly. There are other people at the hostel, and they are paying for wifi too. Isn't 1 mbps enough for you? That's what I have for 3 PCs at home.

Comment: Also, how are you so sure the speed limit is in the router rather than at your PCs?

Comment: @ThatHelpVampireGuy Reply to your comment. A)That's an unethical question : I don't think so. Because most of the time no one is there to utilize the speed. So, it just get unused. B) The only ways to do that are by hacking :  I have wifi router next to my room. I can reset its password physically any but I don't want to do that. C)  If you are going to ask management, then just go and ask for a speed increase, instead of trying to do this sneakingly. : It is not an option. D)  Isn't 1 mbps enough for you? NO, 1mbps (128KBPS) is not enough for me.       Any way thanks for the advise.

Comment: That's unethical because there is a speed limit and a password, both set by someone other than you, and you are asking us how to bypass both (well, bypassing one means bypassing both).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the access point or router is enforcing this bandwidth limit, you can't really do anything on your system to make it to anything differently in that regard.

> So, as an alternate if it is possible to connect to many wifi at same time to increase speed.

You can't take multiple Internet connections and combine their bandwidth in the way you are thinking unless the server, site, or whatever on the other side is cooperating.

If I have three 1Mbps connections to the internet, I cannot download a single web page from a website at 3Mbps unless that site knows I'm trying to connect from three different addresses and we are using a protocol that supports that.  There are protocols that do, but they are not in wide use and your router probably blocks them.

---

In response to your comment below:

If you want different applications on the same system to connect separately to this network and have their own 1Mbps connection, you can do that.  You will need one wifi network adapter per connection.

The easiest way to get an application to use a specific wifi adapter will be to house it in a virtual machine - so install VMWare Player, and then install an OS in that.  VMWare Player lets you "give" USB devices to virtual machines - so then anything running on that VM will use that wifi adapter and you can then connect it to whatever network you want.  So if you do this, get a bunch of USB wifi adapters.

There are ways to get it to work without VMWare player but they are more complex than doing the above.

Comment: Can I combine multiple wifi connection such that chrome use wifi #1, firefox use wifi #2....?

Comment: No. Applications do not [usually] access network devices. They ask the OS to communicate with other IPs. Not to communicate via an specific interface.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine multiple internet connections. Connectify Dispatch or alternatives will work:
http://alternativeto.net/software/connectify-dispatch/

I too have 1 megabit per connection restrictions at a motel I live at. I connect my android phone to the same WIFI, and tether via USB to double my connection/bandwidth. works beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can break the barrier of 1 Mbps. There are two options you have:

1. Using multiple network cards and combining them with a tool such as dispatch-proxy
2. Creating multiple virtual network adapters and configure them to use single physical network adapter and then do second part of first option. I am sure you can easily do this in Linux